# WCF to DB Null exception

Tags: wcf

I am trying to connect WPF to WCF to DB but i am getting null exception 
and i dont know how to debug it or what is going wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace StockWcf
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to 
    change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder;
        void ConnectToDb()
        {
            connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connStringBuilder.DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB";
            connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = @"C:\Projects\Assignment 3\StockApp\StockApp\StockApp.mdf";
            connStringBuilder.Encrypt = true;
            connStringBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            connStringBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
            connStringBuilder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
            connStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            connStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            conn = new SqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ToString());
            comm = conn.CreateCommand();

        }
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }

        public Member GetMember(Member m)
        {
            Member member = new Member();
            try
            {
                comm.CommandText = "select * from Users where username=@username and password=@password";
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", m.username);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", m.password);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    member.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                    member.username = reader[1].ToString();
                    member.firstname = reader[2].ToString();
                    member.lastname = reader[3].ToString();
                    member.email = reader[4].ToString();
                    member.password = reader[5].ToString();
                    member.lastSearchAll = reader[6].ToString();
                    member.lastSearchHistory = reader[7].ToString();
                    member.lastSearchLive = reader[8].ToString();
                }

                return member;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            finally
            {
                if(conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Everytime when i try to debug by setting break points in visual studio and wherever i put it, it just get me straight to catch (throw;) and i dont know what goes wrong can you please help me as i am new to wcf and i dont have much experience with connecting to db in general

http://prntscr.com/nd8tn0

Comment: Instead of just `catch` do a `catch (Exception ex)`. Then put a break-point on your re-throw.  You can inspect the Stack Trace from `ex` to get a better idea which line is giving you an error.  If your breakpoints aren't working, consider using something like Log4Net and capture your stack-trace to a file. Then you will never miss important details like this.

Comment: When do you call ConnectToDb method, if you haven't called ConnectToDb  before running other methods that access  SqlCommand , you  could meet this problem.